# Truncate a string with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working on PySpark with Databricks and I was looking for a way to truncate a string just like the excel right function does.
For example, I would like to change for an ID column in a `DataFrame` `8841673_3` into `8841673`.

Does anybody knows how I should proceed?

Comment: Are the number lengths consistent? Is the underscore always where you are removing from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions with `regexp_extract`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df = spark.createDataFrame([("8841673_3", )], ("id", ))

df.select(regexp_extract("id", "^(\d+)_.*", 1)).show()
# +--------------------------------+
# |regexp_extract(id, ^(\d+)_.*, 1)|
# +--------------------------------+
# |                         8841673|
# +--------------------------------+
```

`regexp_replace`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df.select(regexp_replace("id", "_.*$", "")).show()
# +--------------------------+
# |regexp_replace(id, _.*$, )|
# +--------------------------+
# |                   8841673|
# +--------------------------+
```

or just `split`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

df.select(split("id", "_")[0]).show()
# +---------------+
# |split(id, _)[0]|
# +---------------+
# |        8841673|
# +---------------+
```

Comment: This might have helped OP but it doesn't answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`pyspark.sql.Column.substr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.substr) method:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def left(x, n):
    return x.substr(0, n)

def right(x, n):
    x_len = F.length(x)
    return x.substr(x_len - n, x_len)
```